# Views not updating?

Tags: 7, views

Using d7.4 - I have views within some quicktabs that will not update. It only shows the results for everything created BEFORE the view was created- but not after. The views are for 'most recent, most comments, most viewed, most votes'. The views wont display any content created after the views were created. I have cleared all caches and turned them off- both in the performance config and the views caching set to NONE. Quicktabs are not the problem as the views don't update in the Views preview display (without quicktabs). Any ideas as to what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the filters?

Here I found this, but no solution:
http://drupal.org/node/1193616

I think the best would be filling an issue
http://drupal.org/project/issues/views

Comment: Actually, I figured it out now. It WAS something in the views- I had a flag set- where the flag was required to be checked. Grrr.... it works great now!  Thanks!